# Add listboxitems programmatically C#/XAML windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

GoodDay! Im having a problem in my expandable/ collapsible listbox. Here's my code:

```
bool add = true;
public void AddList() {
    string[] win = { "Windows1", "Windows2" };
        foreach (string value in win)
        {
            ListMain.Items.Add(value);

        }

    }
    public void RemoveList() {
        string[] win = { "Windows1", "Windows2" };
        foreach (string value in win)
        {

            ListMain.Items.Remove(value);

        }
    }
private void ListMain_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (add == true)
        {
            this.AddList();

            add = false;
        }
        else {
            this.RemoveList();
            add = true;
        }
```

My ListMain is the ListBox, so everytime i tapped it, it will create items inside it namely windows1 and windows2, and when i tapped again my listmain, it will remove the windows1 and window2. My problem here is, when i tapped the windows1 or windows2, it automatically removed itself, it seems it shares the same tapped event with the listmain, how can i change the tapped event of the windows1 and windows2. Thanks for understanding. TYIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out the `Tapped` event on the `ListBoxItems` - add an event handler to `Tapped` on the `ListBoxItems` and set `e.Handled = true;` so it doesn't bubble up to the `ListBox`. Of course in your case you don't have access to the `ListBoxItems` so you might need to change your code a bit so that you add `ListBoxItems` explicitly to the `ListBox` and not rely on it to create those for you, e.g.

```
var lbi = new ListBoxItem { Content = value };
lbi.Tapped += this.OnListBoxItemTapped;
ListMain.Items.Add(lbi);

private void OnListBoxItemTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Remember to remove the `ListBoxItems` in the `RemoveList` call and ubsubscribe from the event handlers:

```
lbi.Tapped -= this.OnListBoxItemTapped;
```